# React native camera doesn't return full file path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I just installed the package and I'm trying to access the picture, although I'm getting a directory without the image.

**Dependencies**

```
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-camera": "^3.22.0",
```

**My Code**

```js
takePicture = async () => {
  if (this.camera) {
    const options = {quality: 0.5, base64: true};
    const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
    console.log(data.uri);
  }
};
```

Output `file:///data/user/0/*******/cache/Camera` but the file is missing

```
"deviceOrientation": 1, "height": 3456, "pictureOrientation": 1, "uri": "file:///data/user/0/***/cache/Camera", "width": 4608}
```

Comment: If you log out the data object, does it have any of the relevant attributes like base64 or weight/height data about the photo?

Comment: @TomFinney Yes ...it also logs base64... which is too long to display here

Comment: That's weird that is it has the image attributes but valid direct direct path... sorry I can't help with that. Not too familiar with RN Camera

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/releases/tag/v3.22.1

The issue was fixed by the creator. 18hours ago.. which I didn't know.